# Programmatically get all the 'static const' defined in a Dart class in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Dart and Flutter.

Specifically, I started with what I thought would be a simple problem: to programmatically get all the names of the icons that come with flutter.  I discovered they are defined as 'static const' in the Icons class.  So, how can I programmatically get all of the those names at runtime?

I discovered that there is a 'mirrors' library but that it won't work in flutter.  I tried jsonEncode(Icons) to see what it might do but got the error: "Converting object to an encodable object failed: Icons".

Surely there must be an easy way to get the 'static const' or other properties of a class in Dart programmatically at runtime?

Comment: No, there's no easy way.

Comment: Thanks for your edit to my answer.
The mods refused the edit, but it was correct; I've re-applied it to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [package:analyzer](https://pub.dev/packages/analyzer) to perform static analysis on Dart code. This package is what powers `dartanalyzer`, so it's pretty heavy weight but should be able to accomplish what you're looking to do.

For example, we do something similar to collect all of the types in the core libraries for [fuzz testing in the Dart SDK](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/runtime/tools/dartfuzz/gen_api_table.dart).

Comment: Is there any example?

Comment: yeah probably might make things easier by giving a simple example that illustrates the solution to the problem