# How do I get the names of all classes within a Dart program file?

Tags: dart

I'd like to get the names of all of the Dart classes in a file. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean with `contains one or multiple classes` and with `class name`? Do you need to know if the FileSystemEntity is a File, Directory or a Link?

Comment: @Mattia: My FileSystemEntity is actually a .dart file which has class, for example: myfile.dart has class Foo { // some code } and I want to get the object Type Foo

Comment: Why you would need to do that? All the ways that I can think of are parsing the file manually, or using mirrors (not entirely sure if the will do the job).

Comment: My original problem is, I have a folder which include many .dart files, and I want to get all the name of the class from these files. I used .listSync(recursive: true) and it returns list of FileSystemEntity. I tried dart:mirrors but cannot import it successfully. How parsing would make it work ? Could you provide some code please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically get all the 'static const' defined in a Dart class in Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59463235/programmatically-get-all-the-static-const-defined-in-a-dart-class-in-flutter-a)